# How to have no/one window title and have a different title for the task bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Windows Explorer in Windows 7, and maybe Vista too (can't rememmber), does not have a title in the window. but does have a title (some text) in the taskbar.

Is this possible to reproduce in C# (wpf or winforms)? either through the framework or introp.

I want to have a window that says "Options" in the taskbar but the window itself doesn't have a title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx for the section titled "Vista Explorer – Removing redundant information from the title bar"

Comment: thanks this is 100% what i was looking for. thank you soooo much! i would upvote if i had the rep...

Answer (score 6):

MSDN has a nice article called [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195(loband).aspx) which discusses the things you can do with the window frame using the DWM of Vista and Windows 7. In particular, the *Removing the Standard Frame* section should be relevant for your case.

Comment: wish i could acept both answers. this is also just what i wanted.. thank you soooo much.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following attribute to the Windows element in your .xaml file

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

Side notes:
Task Manager can have a title bar or not have a title bar, depending on what mode you have it in; double click on the margin to toggle the mode.  Also note, the quickest note to bring up Task Manager is Ctrl+Shift+Esc.  Also check out the BorderThickness and WindowsState attributes of the Window element.

Credit to the Particle Effects Example in WPF MSDN docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed a Property of the WPF Window:

**ShowInTaskbar:** 
*Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the window has a task bar button. This is a dependency property.*

I think this may be helpful. You can set WindowStyle Property to "None" with the ShowInTaskbar Property set to "True".